# How do I prove that $m(TE)=\left|\det(T)\right|m(E)$?

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, measure-theory

Let $m$ be the $n$-dimensional Lebesgue measure and $T$ be a linear operator on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Let $\Sigma$ be the sigma-algebra of Lebesgue measurable sets.

How do prove that (1) $\forall E\in\Sigma, T(E)\in \Sigma$ and $m(T(E))=\left|\det(T)\right|m(E)|$?

Since the $\sigma$-algebra of Lebesgue measurable sets is strictly larger than the borel algebra, I think it cannot be proven by showing that $T$ is continuous.

How do I prove this formally?

I have a script from UC Davis and every thing is proven precisely here, except for one lemma which is critical for rest proofs in the script. That is,

> Define $\mathbb{B}=\big\{\prod_{i=1}^n [a_i,b_i) : a_i,b_i\in\mathbb{R}\big\}$.
>
> Let $T$ be a unitary operator on $\mathbb{R}^n$.
>
> Let $A\in \mathbb{B}$ and $\{A_k\}_{1≦k≦m}$ be a finite disjoint sequence such that $\bigcup_{1≦k≦m} A_k \subset T(A)$.
>
> Then $\sum_{1≦k≦m} m(A_k) ≦ m(A)$.

It's written in the script: "This result is geometrically obvious, but a formal proof seems to require a fuller discussion of the volume function on elementary geometrical sets, which is included in the theory of valuation in convex geometry. We omit the details"

It's okay to me to go through full discussion of volume function if that is precise. If it cannot be proven another easier way(so I can prove it in a day), please recommend me a "convex geometry" text which explains this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $T(E) \in \Sigma$ you need to use not only continuity of $T$ but also the fact, that there are bounds of the type $cx < Tx < Cx$ for nonzero constants.

For the formula with $det$ you can use the set of generators of $GL(n)$ -- scalar matrices and $I+E_{ij}$ where $E_{ij}$ are elementary matrices. For such maps it is not hard to show that the image of the rectangle has the desired volume (with  some integration for the generators of the second type).

More details:
You need first to find the measure of the image of the rectangle. That can be done by looking in generators of $GL(n)$. For scalar operators that's trivial. For nonscalar the image would be a trapezoid that lies over the rectangle and whose ``caps'' are just linear. If you have troubles with this do the $2$ and $3$ dimensional case, it is not hard.

To show that $T(E) \in \Sigma$ you need to show that borel maps to borel (that's easy) and that measure zero maps to measure zero. But if you have the cover by rectangles with sum of measures $\varepsilon$ then the image would be covered by something with measure less then $C\varepsilon$. So $T$ preserves $\Sigma$ .

Comment: would you please be more precise? I'm having quite a hard time struggling this.. :( Please help

Comment: here you go $ $